# Thunderbird showing "Unable to locate mail spool file" on installing gmail account in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, thunderbird, mail, gmail

I just configure a gmail account in thunder mail but its continuously showing me error "Unable to locate mail spool file." when i click get mail then also it shows same error.
its not retrieving mail from gmail. 
I tried moving /var/spool to .Thunderbird but that also not working. What to do ??

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/332458/66118 same problem

Comment: cool but i got solution

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure thunderbird is closed.

Just go to the file browser and type CTRL+H to reveal hidden files, then delete the .thunderbird folder.

After that, thunderbird should open fine.

Comment: i think i got the solution for that you just have to generate a application specific password use this [link][1]


  [1]: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

I was creating a [localhost only environment](https://gist.github.com/raelgc/6031274) to test email sending during development and faced this error message.

The reason was: my user spool mail file was really empty.

To solve it, I just composed an email to myself and clicked on `Get Messages`. Spool created and problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

after making sure Thunderbird is closed, from the shell do
  `cd ~/ && rm -r ./thunderbird`

Comment: Isn't it better to rename the folder before removing it forever to make sure it solves the problem without losing important data?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this post.  Renaming the hidden file in-home/me to .thunderbird.old so when I opened TB mail, it wanted to do an automatic setup.  Why is there not an automatic setup offered without having to do this?  The auto-setup takes our name (account ID), your email@address.net and your Password you put in and guesses the IMAP and SMTP and also SSL and all that for you.  It worked for me.  Oh, and just be sure to re-order the messages as they list upside down by default.