# Thunderbird mail

Tags: email

I am not able to send Emails.

I get the following message -

```
Sending of message failed.
Please verify that your Mail & Newsgroups account settings are correct and try again.
```

**About Mail & Newsgroups account settings.**

I know nothing about these type of settings and only want to send Emails. I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and Thunderbird mail.

The Thunderbird help site do not answer this problem.

Comment: Do you receive emails in Thunderbird?

Comment: I have only opened Thunderbird one day ago and do not know if i receive Emails. My mail address is heldemanpieter@gmail.com. I am very very new to all of this and know less than a cat about this.

Comment: Did you check out all cases in this: https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/cannot-send-messages?

Comment: @SimplySimon - does thunderbird work now currently in Ubuntu (vivid vervid)? here not, and where is detailed howto for to adjust snmtp and pop correctly ? to me it looks as if this is humblesome, since gandhi.net is out there before you  want to log-in with thunderbird ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?

It shows necessary configure steps for your GMail account, as well as links to both automatic and manual configuration of Thunderbird.

https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/Thunderbird-and-Gmail

Update: did some google searching for you. Here's a similar problem with a solution that is not confirmed.

Check it out:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1607991&p=11906852#post11906852

Comment: Sounds good. I will go there and check it out. Never got this type of help with MS.

Comment: I now get the message - Unable to locate mail spool file. - What is a mail spool file. Is it something that I must install.

Comment: I'm guessing that you've setup some kind of "linux internal mail" account instead of an IMAP/POP3 account.

Comment: Ok. I am un-installing Tbird and re-install. Will be back.

Comment: I have re-installed. Clicking on Tbird icon it opens and immediately on top give a small alert window with --  Unable to locate mail spool file.

Comment: @heldeman I updated my answer.

Comment: Cant fix Tbird then tried Claws with the same problem. Installed Sypheed and no problems. It seems to be a niece package. Thanks for all the help.